# Is there an idiomatic way to solve small isolated independent task with CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

I wrote my first CUDA program which I am trying to speed up. I ask myself if this is possible since the problem is not really appropriate for SMID-Processing (Single instruction, multiple data). It is more a "single function, multiple data" problem. I have many similar tasks to be solved independently.

My current approach is:

```
__device__ bool solve_one_task_on_device(TaskData* current){    
    // Do something completely independent of other threads (no SMID possible).
    // In my case each task contains an array of 100 elements,
    // the function loops over this array and often backtracks 
    // depending on its current array value until a solution is found.
}

__global__ void solve_all_tasks_in_parallel(TaskData* p, int count){
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ;
    if(i < count) {
        solve_one_task_on_device(&p[i]);
    }
}

main {
...
    // tasks_data is an array of e.g 4096 tasks (or more) copied to device memory
    solve_all_tasks_in_parallel<<<64, 64>>>(tasks_data, tasks_data_count);  
...
}
```

What would be the idiomatic way to do it? If it should be done at all.
I already read some threads about the topic. I have 512 CUDA cores. What I am less sure is if each CUDA Core can really independently solve a task so that
instructions are not synchronized. How many task-parallel threads can I start and what would be the recommended way to do the parallelization?

It is an experiment, I want to see if CUDA is useful for such problems at all.
Currently running my function in parallel on the CPU is much faster. I guess I cannot get similar performance on my GPU unless I have a SMID problem, correct?

My hardware is:

```
CPU: Xeon E5-4650L (16 Cores)
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro P620
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.1 / 9.1
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
```

Comment: It is important that neighbouring threads (within a warp) take the same code path most of the time but not always. Memory access can be scattered, loop counts can vary (within reason), but you cannot have something like ```if(a) long_loop(); else different_loop();``` within a warp unless you want to tank performance. So it depends on the details of your ```solve_one_task``` function

Comment: Those divergences can exist in the code, but the chance of them occurring at runtime in the same warp (group of 32 threads) must be low

Comment: Do *not* scatter global memory accesses. Better load it into shared memory. Use shared memory a lot, you can access it with indices (unlike registers) and the threads of a warp may converge again (depending on your backtracking). You should decide, (except loading memory from global to shared), whether each thread solves an independent task or each warp. Even if you do not need 32 threads all the time for one task, you can sometimes use a few cooperative threads. Diverging threads take 32x as much of computing resources. Cuda has lots of those. It will probably still beat the CPU.

Comment: Think about, whether you can speed up your algorithm by predictive execution, precomputation and so on. Perhaps some of those auxiliary tasks can be parallelized and would be cheap, but help your main algorithm. E.g. if it is a mathematical graph, which you follow, you could calculate a table with all the cross connections. If it is pattern matching you could try to match at several (32) positions at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps the tasks are similar enough, that you only have divergencies on between and can converge again. Perhaps you have to reformulate or transform the data first to make the execution of your tasks a bit more similar.

Comment: Perhaps the tasks have sub-steps A to Z (with repeats) in an order, which is only determined at runtime. Then you can collect those sub-steps over each task in a todo list. Each warp only executes 32 same type sub-steps, stores the next needed step (which may differ between threads) into the list, and executes 32 sub-steps of possibly different tasks, but of again the same type.

Comment: Use Nvidia Compute Nsight to find the real bottleneck. Often with such kernels it is not actually the diverging computation, but the global memory loads and stores. Even with L1 and L2 caches you lose a lot of bandwidth, if you do not care to keep an eye on it.

Comment: With Pascal you can start between 64 to 2048 tasks per SM. 64, when using one task per warp, 64 is the maximum number of warps per SM. 2048, when doing 1 task per thread. Numbers in between are possible, e.g. you could have 4 neighboring threads cooperate for the same task, so that each warp processes 8 tasks. Less than 64 per SM is possible, if you do not have enough registers, not enough shared memory, the L1 and L2 caches are used more inefficientently or your overall number of tasks is too low.

Comment: The P620 contains only 4 SM. It is rather small, as far as GPUs go (about 10x slower than a current medium range GPU). The P620 has 96 KB of shared memory per SM. If your 100 elements per task need 4 bytes each, you could afford (theoretically) 245 tasks per SM, that is if it cannot be done with registers instead. I would do either 64, 128 or 192 tasks per SM doing 1, 2 or 3 tasks per warp. That would be 256, 384 or 512 tasks at the same time for the whole GPU.

Comment: Each Pascal SM is in turn partitioned into 2 processing blocks (similar to CPU Cores) and each Pascal processing block can do 2 (32x SIMD) instructions at the same time, similar to hyperthreading on a CPU, where 1 core executes 2 threads concurrently. So your graphics card is architecturally best comparable to an 8 core processor with hyperthreading, slow clock speeds, relatively (your memory speed is not the best for a GPU, but compared to a CPU) fast memory and superior multithreading and far superior SIMD capability. It could still beat your CPU for that difficult task or be on par with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments. My academic case study was a "Sudoku" - backtracking algorithm that I implemented in different programming languages. Moving the data from device memory and also constant memory to shared memory improved my solution slightly, but not much (in the case I measured, I gained around 10% performance). However, I know that you cannot compare the CPU to a GPU. I guess unless I would own an extremely powerful GPU, I am better of with the CPU for such kinds of problems (my RUST program is e.g. is 38x faster in solving 100.000 Sudokus, also multi-threaded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 512 CUDA cores.

Remember "CUDA cores" is just NVIDIA marketing speech. You don't have 512 cores. A Quadro P620 has 4 cores; and on each of them, multiple warps of 32 threads each can execute the same instruction (for all 32). So, 4 warps, each executing an instruction, on each of 4 cores, makes 512. In practice, you usually get less than 512 instructions executing per clock cycle.

> What I am less sure is if each CUDA Core can really independently solve a task so that instructions are not synchronized.

So, no. But if you arrange your tasks so that the *logic* is the same for many of them and only the *data* is different, then there's a good chance you'll be able to execute these tasks in parallel, effectively. Of course there are many other considerations, like data layout, access patterns etc to keep in mind.

On different cores, and even on the same core with different warps, you can run very different tasks, completely independently past the point in the kernel where you choose your task and code paths diverge.